# Add an image to an XML file and parse it on Google Maps API v3

Tags: xml, google-maps

I'm trying to add a category "image" to an XML file with markers that are rendered on a Google Map with a sidebar. 
The XML has this structure

```
marker lat="0" lng="0" html="text" label="sidebar label" image="image.jpg"
```

What I want is to add to the sidebar label, next to the each text entry, an image, whose source is defined by the field 'image' on the XML.

Also, we want this image to appear on the map bubble. Below is the code we have.
I'm not an expert and all my tests have failed.

I'll be grateful for any suggestion or advice on this.
Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
  var side_bar_html = ""; 
  var gmarkers = []; 
  var map = null;

function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: 'monumento.png',
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

gmarkers.push(marker);
side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';

 }

function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 17,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.777557,-80.15065),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

  downloadUrl("casas_famosos.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      // obtain the attribues of each marker    
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
      var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");       
      var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
  });
 }
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)

});
 //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: The "XML" structure described in your question is not XML.  It's hard to know what's going on here.

Comment: Can you post the contents of casas_famosos.xml, or at least an excerpt from it?  If the problem is in the XML file, it may be difficult or impossible to tell from just your code.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it more simple. Thank you for answering. This is the XML:

`<markers>
 <marker lat="12.77" lng="1.15" html="Restaurant on the beach"  label="Restaurant"  imagen="restaurant_beach_thumbnail.jpg" />
</markers>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the image from the XML when you get all the other XML attributes, then add it to the html that appears in the infowindow, like this:

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, image) {
    var contentString = image + html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: 'monumento.png',
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    gmarkers.push(marker);
    side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + image + name + '<\/a><br>';
}

...

downloadUrl("casas_famosos.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        // obtain the attribues of each marker    
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
        var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
        var image = '<img src="'+markers[i].getAttribute("image")+'" alt=""/>';      
        var marker = createMarker(point,label,html,image);
    }
```

Note that I'm assuming that the images are in the same directory as the HTML.  If not, you'll have to adjust the generated `img` tag appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, Trott! It works. Just one more question, if possible. How can I add this same image to the sidebar item?